# Excel formula minutes to hours in text format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to convert minutes to hours in text format

text minutes = 291

How to convert it to 4.51 (means 4hrs 51min)

I don't use time format or ":" because have a lot data to key in, number pad is good for key in much data.

Thanks help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
=TEXT(291/1440,"[h].mm")
```

Not sure what you meant with *"I don't use time format or ":" because have a lot data to key in, number pad is good for key in much data."*. But the above returns a text-string of `4.51`.

The `[h]` is meant to count beyond 24 hours if `291` could exceed `1440`.

Comment: Hi Thanks! This is the best answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do use the CONCAT and MOD function and do something like the example below.

I'm giving pseudo-code as you haven't specified any cell ranges.

```
= CONCAT(INT((text minutes)/60), '.',MOD((text minutes),60)
```

Remember that the CONCAT method returns a string and not an integer.

Comment: You need to wrap the first calculation with `INT` or you'll get 4.85.51.

Comment: Thank you! Your formula works! Here is my code: `=CONCATENATE(INT((textMin)/60),".",MOD(INT(textMin),60))`

Comment: @pykam Hi, I get some error there, 
`hrs=10`, 
`min=231`, 
`=CONCATENATE(INT(((10*60)-231)/60),".",MOD(((10*60)-231),60))`
why I get answer = 6.9 ?

Comment: Sorry don't understand why you are doing a subtraction here `(10*60)-231)`

Comment: `((10*60)-231)` `10 is hours` and `231 min` means `((600)-231)/60`